# Crontab for every odd Saturday

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

How do I set the crontab for every odd saturday (or other weekday) ?

Few crontabs I have tried:

- `0 22 */7 * 6`
- `0 22 * * 6` (This is every saturday)

Comment: Have you checked on this? https://serverfault.com/questions/633264/cronjob-run-every-two-weeks-on-saturday-starting-on-this-saturday

Comment: Yeah, I had. Actually, I was trying for an inbuilt command in crontab itself. For example: `1-59/2 * * * *` runs every odd minute.